# How do I create cascading select lists from Metafield JSON in Shopify?

Tags: jquery, json, shopify, dropdown

We sell auto parts and each part only fits certain years, makes, models, submodels, etc. Since our variants exceed Shopify's limits, I'm considering adding a metefield for each part that would include a JSON description of all the possible combinations available for that vehicle. I'd like to parse that data into a series of cascading dropdown select lists on the product page. Using the JSON example below, if you choose 1973 in the first select list, then you could choose Chevrolet or GMC in the second select list. The third list would show the available models, and a forth select list would allow users to choose Liters, and so on.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to feed this JSON data into select lists in the product liquid, and I'm not even sure if the JSON is formatted properly. Can anyone help me get started or lead me to a resource that could help me learn next steps for displaying this data on my Shopify product liquid. Again, keep in mind that this JSON will be stored in a metafield.

The following is an example of the metafield JSON for one part:

```
{"VEHICLES":[{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K20 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"4.1"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K20 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"4.8"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K20 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"5.0"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K20 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"5.7"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K20 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"7.4"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K30 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"4.1"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K30 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"4.8"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K30 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"5.0"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K30 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"5.7"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"Chevrolet","Model":"K30 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"7.4"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K25/K2500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"4.1"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K25/K2500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"4.8"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K25/K2500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"5.7"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K25/K2500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"7.4"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K35/K3500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"4.1"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K35/K3500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"4.8"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K35/K3500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"5.0"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K35/K3500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"5.0"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K35/K3500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"5.7"},{"Year":"1973","Make":"GMC","Model":"K35/K3500 Pickup","Submodel":"","Liter":"7.4"},]}
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that pattern. Storing JSON in a metafield is fine, but only the front-end client-side Javascript will be able to parse JSON and deal with it. So assuming you encode products with a JSON Payload informing your front-end of what that product is all about, good luck writing front-end code that then makes the Shopify product experience better.

By that I mean you're now going to be able to do what? Somehow ensure the customer is shown only the right products? Or that the filter from the JSON data possibly ensures the customer gets the correct variant?

Comment: Thanks David. That makes sense. Yes, a part of this is simply to ensure that the customer chooses available variants and doesn't order a product that doesn't fit their vehicle. I would also hope, as you noted, that we could use this to create a fitment selector for the home page and category pages. The problem is that most of our products are similar to the one I listed (lots of variations, but no change in SKU), but some of our products are true variants (i.e., if you change the color or size it changes the SKU). In short, I'm having trouble coming up with a meaningful data model that works.

Comment: I kinda grok. Some time ago I was tasked with making a shop to sell tires. Make, Model Year data led to selections of tires. A vast and not quite ready for primetime e-commerce domain...

Comment: How do you expect the customer action flow? The way I see it you can have all this JSON data loaded into a file and then let the customer choose his options and then take him to the right product. No? I have done something similar and it helps if you can reduce number of data points and increase the levels in your JSON.

Comment: @HymnZ, the problem is that often our customers land on product pages directly from an external site (e.g., through advertising or organic search), so we still need to provide options for selecting everything on the product page. Yes, often customers will search to find their products and end up with the correct part to begin with, but they don't always use search or facets on our site to find the products.

Comment: If you can apply proper logic as what you intend your customer to see or land on which page, it can be done. Implementation is easy as you already have a JSON schema in place.

Comment: @HymnZ. I couldn't find a way to PM you. Is there any chance I could talk with you further about this. I'm not sure if you do development work or can make some recommendations.

Comment: @Bonaventure PM is not available here. But check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you intend, you JSON structure should also be in the same levels as you described to make it easier.

Have your data arranged like this:

```
var Vehicles = {
    'Years' : ['1973'],
    '1973' : {
        'Make' : ['Chevrolet', 'GMC'],
        'Chervolet' : {
            'Models' : ['K20 Pickup', 'K30 Pickup'],
            'K20 Pickup' : {
                'Liters' : ['4.1', '4.8', '5.0', '5.7', '7.4'],
                '4.1' : '<link>',
                '4.8' : '<link>',
                '5.0' : '<link>',
                '5.7' : '<link>',
                '7.4' : '<link>'
            },
            'K30 Pickup' : {
                'Liters' : ['4.1', '4.8', '5.0', '5.7', '7.4'],
                '4.1' : '<link>',
                '4.8' : '<link>',
                '5.0' : '<link>',
                '5.7' : '<link>',
                '7.4' : '<link>'
            }
        },
        'GMC' : {
            'Models' : ['K25/K2500 Pickup', 'K35/K3500 Pickup'],
            'K25/K2500 Pickup' : {
                'Liters' : ['4.1', '4.8', '5.0', '5.7', '7.4'],
                '4.1' : '<link>',
                '4.8' : '<link>',
                '5.0' : '<link>',
                '5.7' : '<link>',
                '7.4' : '<link>'
            },
            'K35/K3500 Pickup' : {
                'Liters' : ['4.1', '4.8', '5.0', '5.7', '7.4'],
                '4.1' : '<link>',
                '4.8' : '<link>',
                '5.0' : '<link>',
                '5.7' : '<link>',
                '7.4' : '<link>'
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

It'll be easier to track the structure and also to retrieve the fields. For example, when someone selects "Chervolet", you just need to get values from `Vehicles['1973']['Chervolet']['Models']` to populate your third dropdown.

P.S. There is a way where you can directly call the "keys" in each JSON object but I have not had a good success rate with it so I can't advice.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot more sense. I'll do my best to see if I can produce the corresponding script to consume this structure. I may have more questions when I dig in, but this is a great start. Thanks again.